# How I combine two wifi networks into one?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, raspberry-pi

In the work I have two wifi, the `wifi_1` is a internal network, don´t have internet and the IP rank is `10.10.01.X`, the `wifi_2` have access to other service what the `wifi_1` don´t have and a limited internet connection, the IP rank es `192.168.0.X`.

Is posible combine this wifi networks using linux? redirecting all 10.10.10.X request to wifi_1 and other request to wifi_2. 
My idea is use a Raspberry pi3 with two wifi adapters and share this via LAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. That is what a router is ;)

You will have a router (your raspberry here) which will have 3 network interfaces :

- wifi1
- wifi2
- Third one

You configure it to route packets comming from The 3rd interface with :

- destination network 10.10.01.0/24 to interface wifi1
- everything else to interface wifi2

Your computer will be in the network of the third interface and will have to use your raspberry as the gateway.

```
                                  Raspberry Pie
                             +------------------------+
                             |                        |
                             |                  wifi 1+--------->  10.10.01.0/24
                             |                        |
+---------------+            |                        |
| your computer | +--------> | 3rd interface          |
+---------------+            |                        |
                             |                        |
                             |                  wifi 2+--------->  Every thing else
                             |                        |
                             +------------------------+
```

Comment: @Isma90 or you can add a wifi dongle on your laptop and connect to the 2 wifi at the same time and let your OS deal with the routing table :p

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to set up the routers in Wireless Distribution System (WDS) mode. However, you would need access to the router admin interfaces, and both routers would need to support WDS. Also, WDS is not really standardised, so theoretically you could find that the two wifi routers don't work well together using WDS. But this can work.

The downside is WDS merges the two networks into one, so they would need to have the exact same IP address range, share one DHCP server, and there would be no security segregation between them. Also, it essentially makes router 2 act as a "wireless repeater", so packets to be sent between the two wireless networks get repeated (duplicated), in effect halving the available bandwidth and increasing latency. So a WDS is not always appropriate.